# vim cannot quit paste mode

Tags: vim, insert, paste, vi

I ssh to my ubuntu server from mac, and type vi command. I paste some text, and then every shortcut is invalid. `esc` becomes `^[`, `command + c` not work, and I have to terminate my session. What happened, and what should i do to reenter vi command mode

the problem looks like this:

```
some text pasted[201~
^[^[^[^[^[^[
^C
^?
~
~
~
-- INSERT (paste)--  // sometimes just '-- INSERT --'
```

I tried `command + c`, `command + q`, and failed

Comment: Did you try `:set nopaste`?

Comment: @dlmeetei First the OP wants to exit Insert mode.